# Show div past certain page height 'active' on page load

Tags: javascript, html

hope someone can provide some guidance here. I have got some JS which tells the div to slide in to view after the user scrolls past the set Y point.

However, on page load, the div is still visible until you start scrolling. then it disappears and then slides in when its meant to.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
      $('.mobileEnquiry').slideUp();
    } else {
      $('.mobileEnquiry').slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px
}
.mobileEnquiry {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobileEnquiry"></div>
```

Anyone know why this happens? I have tried a couple of things. Firstly, moving it out of the 'on page load' section of my JS however that did nothing. Then I have looked around and tried different methods but none have worked.

Comment: why not have it display none from the start ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Oh wow - yes that would work. *Hits head on desk*. cheers

Comment: sidenote, you're probably going to be doing a lot of work in that event listener. IIRC scrollTop triggers a forced synchronous layout that's likely to cause some jank. You might want to look at debouncing that callback. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `slideUp()` Method **Hide** the matched elements with a sliding motion. and the `slideDown()` Method, **Display** the matched elements with a sliding motion. So:

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $( document ).scroll( function() {
    var y = $( this ).scrollTop();
    ( y > 800 ) ? $( '.mobileEnquiry' ).slideDown() : $( '.mobileEnquiry' ).slideUp();
  } )
} )
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px
}
.mobileEnquiry {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobileEnquiry"></div>
```